# Moving items between two list boxes. What do you call this type of form?

Tags: user-interface, forms, naming

What do you call a form with two list boxes and buttons to move the list box items from one to the other?  I've always called it a "switch list".

[Switch List http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/9123/formtypegh0.png](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/9123/formtypegh0.png)

Comment: I've chosen a winner based upon the number of votes.

Comment: Multiple Selection from a Small List is another possibility: http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main/ViewPattern$pattern=Multiple+Selection+from+a+Small+List

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mutually exclusive list

Comment: Seems logical... I like that, I think I might prefer it to my Subset Selection Dialog.

Comment: I'd buy "mutually exclusive list selection dialog" or simply "List Selection Dialog," but a Mutually Exclusive List could be any list that is mutually exclusive (a dictionary, for example).

Answer (score 2):

[Double List](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/salaakso/patterns/Double-List.html)?

Answer (score 2):

To be very honest, I always thought it was called simply **"Moving items between two list boxes"**.

Comment: Yes but we need something that produces a nice acronym - this is after all the I.T. industry... MIBTLB doesn't exactly roll off the tongue :P

Comment: "Juggling Between Listboxes" - JBL, maybe ?

Comment: and include the word dialog... we need to know it's packaged nicely :P JBL dialog or JBLD lol

Answer (score 2):

Subset Selection Dialog

Answer (score 1):

As silly as it may sound, I've always gone with "Dual-list Selector".  Highly technical.

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Where I work we call it an "Add Remove Box". Don't know why, it just happened that way and it has seem to stick.

Comment: Why does that remind me of the "Add Remove Programs" thingy in Windows ?

Comment: I don't know, but I thought the same thing the first time I heard it. I even made a comment, but apparently it was already engrained with everyone else so I just went with it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch list is nice.

Exchange dialog is also fine.

Btw, do you also have a drag/drop interface?

Comment: I must admit that I've implemented this without drag/drop in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be a bit clearer about the functionality here ..

The way you showed it, it's basically a different way of doing a list that allows multiple selection (then I'd call it a 'chooser').

The more typical usage scenario I've seen is with some ordering functionality (implicit - the new item gets added to the bottom, or explicit with up/down/top/bottom buttons) to put the things in the 'added' list in a certain order.

Not sure what I'd call it then, because it's choosing and ordering .. ordered list chooser or selector.

Comment: Yes, it is a glorified multiple selection box. I personally don't like it, but users seem to.