# What do you call this user interface control?

Tags: user-interface, listbox

What do you call this interface control.

You have 2 lists, one of the lists acts as your pool and the other as your current values. Tends to look like this

```
[1    ]               [1     ]
[2    ]     Add>>     [2     ]
[3    ]   Add All>>   [      ]
[4    ]    <Remove    [      ]
[5    ] <<Remove All  [      ]
[6    ]               [      ]
```

The source list does not change regardless of the operations.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492897/moving-items-between-two-list-boxes-what-do-you-call-this-type-of-form/

Comment: Not duplicate; here he's showing he can have the same values in both columns; in the link you provided they are really mutually exclusive.

Comment: That's right, the source list is not changed based on the actions

Comment: judging by the humorous nature of the answers below, I'd say we have an opportunity to decide on a semi-official (SO-offical, anyways) name for this control.  That might draw the ire of the "close all the questions you possibly can" crowd, though.

Comment: I agree, this kind of control is used so much it should have a name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called a Collector according to Alan Cooper in About Face. Sari Laasko says Double List in her [gallery](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/salaakso/patterns/Double-List.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pool-and-current-values-lists widget

Answer (score 1):

Ordered multi-selection gadget

or

Two-lists-four-buttons extravaganza

promoting comment to answer:

I suggest to call control where you move items between lists: Ping Pong, and this one: Ping Pong against a wall

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this called **LeftRightMultiSelect**, or something like that, before.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably called different things in different environments. In struts2 there is a UI widget called a **optiontransferselect** that does what you describe. I'm sure the same thing is called by a different name in a desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

StaticLeftMultiSelectControl

Answer (score 0):

Font/DA Mover

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking - although unlike the described control, Font/DA Mover was able to affect both lists.

Answer (score 0):

"Subselection control"?